# What is the difference between a battery and a "polarized" charged capacitor?

Tags: terminology, capacitance, electrical-engineering, batteries

I know that the main difference between the two is that a battery can provide a constant voltage whereas a capacitor's voltage decreases as the charge stored decreases. 
But what about the internal structure ? 
A battery also has chemical reactions going inside of it while a **polarized** capacitor also has an electrolytic structure.
So is there or is there not any difference between the internal workings of a **polarized** capacitor and a battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batteries produce a charge difference across the terminals as a result of a chemical reaction. A chemical gets changed into another one. Even in a rechargeable battery a chemical change takes place that is reversed.

An electrolytic capacitor uses chemistry to create a thin layer with an electric field across it. The thinner layer than a "regular" capacitor allows more charge to be stored in a smaller space. But the fundamental difference is that there is no chemical change when a capacitor is charged

Comment: and a capacitor once it loses its charge no watthours to replace it. In other words a battery can charge a capacitor but a capacitor cannot charge a battery :).

Comment: @annav, a *charged* capacitor can at least partially charge a battery, i.e., a *discharging* capacitor supplies power to the attached circuit whether the circuit is a resistor or a battery.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri true, but very transient, no wattshours

Comment: @annav, for example, this 3000F 2.7V capacitor stores 3Wh at rated voltage:  http://www.maxwell.com/products/ultracapacitors/docs/datasheet_k2_series_1015370.pdf

Comment: @AlfredCentauri my point is that a battery stores appreciable energy for use when needed. A capacitor is not a good choice for energy storage.

Comment: @annav, technology advances are rapidly rendering your last sentence false.  See for example:  http://www.gizmag.com/toyota-details-yaris-hybrid-r/28827/

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, impressive (and vapourware) but it's still only 40hp for 10secs (80 WHr). Another interesting vehicle application is using supercaps with the starter motors of heavy trucks, so you don't need huge lead-acid cells to cold crank a big diesel. Supercaps can provide vast currents, even if limited energy